# sharepoint anonymous asking to login when i clicked page in the site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010

I enabled anonymous access to all the web pages in my sharepoint site. But in 1 page i added a tag cloud. When i am opening the page(with anonymous access), the page is asking for login. If i click cancel, then there is no error page is coming. And if the user is signed in to the site, he is able to see the flash tag cloud. how to enable the flash tag cloud to anonymous access?

Comment: and i am using javascript only in that usercontrol.

Comment: javascript code:<script src="../jscripts/swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var flashVars = {
 tcolor: '0x111111',
 tcolor2: '0xffffff',
 hicolor: '0x',
 tspeed: 400,
 distr: true,
 mode: 'tags'
};
swfobject.embedSWF('../jscripts/tagcloud.swf?xmlpath=tags.aspx', 'tagcloud', '225', '200', '9.0.0', flashVars);
</script>

<div id="tagcloud">Please install Flash version 10+ to see the tag cloud.</div>

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that something on that page refers to a resource (such as a javascript, image file, or css) that requires authentication, and when you click cancel, the rest of the page loads, but that resource fails to load.

Try using firebug in firefox to monitor the files that are requested for that page and look to see which files get a 401 Unauthorized error.  You could then either make changes to ensure that those files are available to anonmyous users or change the page so that it no longer needs those files.